# Why can't I find termcap library when I build gdb?

Tags: centos, make, build, gdb, autotools

`make` and then failed with:

**configure: error: no termcap library found**, but that termcap lib is just there, why can't make find it?

```
checking for library containing zlibVersion... -lz
checking zlib.h usability... yes
checking zlib.h presence... yes
checking for zlib.h... yes
checking for library containing dlgetmodinfo... no
checking for iconv... yes
checking for iconv declaration... install-shextern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
checking for library containing waddstr... no
configure: WARNING: no enhanced curses library found; disabling TUI
checking for library containing tgetent... no
configure: error: no termcap library found
make[1]: *** [configure-gdb] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/tmp/gdb-7.5'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I configure gdb with:

```
[mirror@hugemeow gdb-7.5]$ ./configure --libdir=/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/lib/


checking where to find the target readelf... host tool
checking where to find the target strip... host tool
checking where to find the target windres... host tool
checking where to find the target windmc... host tool
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether -fkeep-inline-functions is supported... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

**that tempcap library is just there as I configured to gdb**:

```
[mirror@hugemeow gdb-7.5]$ ls /var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/lib/
libtermcap.a
[mirror@hugemeow gdb-7.5]$ ls /var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/include/
termcap.h
```

**Edit 1**: failed either, even with --includedir and --libdir option...

```
[mirror@hugemeow gdb-7.5]$ ./configure --includedir=/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/include/  --libdir=/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/lib/
make
    checking for library containing tgetent... no
configure: error: no termcap library found
make[1]: *** [configure-gdb] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/tmp/gdb-7.5'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Edit 2**: Now I build as Patrice Tisserand told, but also failed, with different error message as follows.

[mirror@hugemeow gdb-7.5]$ CFLAGS="-I/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/lib/" ./configure && make

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/tmp/gdb-7.5'
Configuring in ./intl
configure: loading cache ./config.cache
configure: error: `CFLAGS' has changed since the previous run:
configure:   former value:  `-g -O2'
configure:   current value: `-I/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/include/'
configure: error: `LDFLAGS' has changed since the previous run:
configure:   former value:  ` '
configure:   current value: ` -L/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/lib/'
configure: error: in `/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/tmp/gdb-7.5/intl':
configure: error: changes in the environment can compromise the build
configure: error: run `make distclean' and/or `rm ./config.cache' and start over
make[1]: *** [configure-intl] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/tmp/gdb-7.5'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 20):

Installing libncurses will solve your problem. Try this if you are using any Debian OS: 
`sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev`.

Comment: I was banging my head on this because I failed to notice that I'd installed plain `libncurses` and not the development package.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. By the way on OpenSUSE it is `ncurses-devel` package.

Answer (score 3):

```
./configure --includedir=/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/include/  --libdir=/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/lib/
```

**--includedir** and **--libdir** are options for **installation** directories.

In order to use libraries from another directories, you can try to do the following:

```
CFLAGS="-I/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/lib/" ./configure
```

Comment: now i build as you tell me, but also failed, with different error message as follows. see edit 2

Comment: hello, did you try to do make distclean as suggested in message output ?

Answer (score 2):

This was extremely helpful: http://archive09.linux.com/feature/121735

> This example shows how to succeed when you find a target-native
>   termcap library is missing (cross building is somewhat different here
>   -- use ./configure --help when in doubt):
>
> ```
> cd ~/work/cross/gdb/downloads
> wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/termcap/termcap-1.3.1.tar.gz
> cd ..
> tar xvzf downloads/termcap-1.3.1.tar.gz
> mkdir -p ~/work/cross/gdb/build/termcap
> cd ~/work/cross/gdb/build/termcap
>
> export CC=powerpc-7450-linux-gnu-gcc
> export RANLIB=powerpc-7450-linux-gnu-ranlib
> ../../termcap-1.3.1/configure --host=powerpc-7450-linux-gnu --prefix=$HOME/work/cross/termcap
> make
> make install
> ```

Comment: You really don't want to override target like that, it will begin looking for that path **at runtime**, on the remote target where that path doesn't exist.  `make DESTDIR=$HOME/work/cross install` works around that problem, but doesn't help find the build dependencies

Answer (score 0):

When building crash tool (which also builds gdb) for 32-bit ARM from x86_64 host I've got similar issue which can be fixed by installing appropriate 32-bit version of ncurses. For Debian OS:

`sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5-dev`

maybe someone will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For last error after **Edit2**,

```
$ mkdir newbuild
$ CFLAGS="-I/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/var/lib/gforge/chroot/home/users/mirror/ins/ins-gdb/lib/" ../configure
$ make
```

Or you can run previous configure commands, `make distclean` firstly, and try again.